# How do I override the websocket timeout value in Phoenix?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to override the default timeout of 60s for websocket connections in config/dev.exs.

I know that I can override the timeout in MyAppWeb.Endpoint.ex like

```
socket "/socket", MyAppWeb.UserSocket,
    websocket: [timeout: :infinity],
    longpoll: false
```

but wonder if I can achieve the same via an entry in config/dev.exs

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question properly, you just put the value in `config.exs`, and read it from where you need it.

```elixir
# config.exs
config :my_app_web, :socket_timeout, :infinity

# usage
socket "/socket", MyAppWeb.UserSocket,
    websocket: [timeout: Application.get_env(:my_app_web, :socket_timeout, 60_000)],
    longpoll: false
```